# Lambda SQS queue consumer error handling with more than 1 record?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

It's easy if I set `Batch Size` to 1 because if:

- Lambda returns truthy, SQS considers it a success and deletes message from queue
- If Lambda throws or doesn't return at all, SQS doesn't delete the message

---

```
// example code
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  event.Records.forEach(record => {
    try {
      const body = JSON.parse(record.body);
      processMessage(body);
    } catch(err) {
      throw err;
    }
  });

  // if execution made this
  // far, everything is fine
  return {};
};


function processMessage(record) {
  // process single message

  if (somethingWentWrong) throw new Error('heck');
}
```

---

But as soon as I add more than 1 message into batch which is a lot more efficient, I can't just throw because all other successful messages will be processed but not deleted from queue.

How to solve this issue (besides leaving batch size to 1)?

Comment: i think the batch messages in sqs are reported individually correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: I can't find any data on that, Lambda can only return a single response as far as I know. Are you suggesting that Lambda should return array or something like that?